# Global cross-application pages or some other UI objects in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

Is there a possibility in Oracle Apex create some objects that can use in other some apps in the workplace?

I have some apps implemented some functionality, but I need in cross-app menu list for link them. And, maybe, one or more global page, which I can edit one time (in main app), but it was impact for all pages in other apps.

I done cross-app authorization and now I can copy menu list for all apps.
Is there some easier good practice for this?

Answer (score 2):

### Menus

For menus, you can create a dynamic (table-based) menu, and then this can be used in all your applications.  To minimise the SQL to be repeated between applications you can hide most in a view used like this:

```
select menu_level
     , label
     , target 
     , is_current_list_entry
     , icon
  from my_dynamic_menu_view
 order by seq
```

In fact you can go further and use a function returning a SQL query like this:

```
return my_menu_pkg.menu_query;
```

### Global page

You cannot have a global page shared between applications.  However, if you want a common region across applications - e.g. for a common page header - you could consider using a PL/SQL region on each application's global page with source like:

```
my_global_package.render_header_region;
```

The procedure would use `sys.htp.prn` calls to render the common HTML e.g.

```
procedure render_header_region is
begin
  sys.htp.prn('<div class="my-header">');
  -- More stuff
  sys.htp.prn('</div>');
end;
```

Other ways to achieve this could be a plug-in region type shared across the applications (publish/subscribe) or even a shared bespoke region template that contains all the common HTML.

Comment: Your APEX password there is no longer valid.  I don't know anything about this translation problem though.